# How to Convert from Pyspark dataframe to pyspark sql code

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

My data frame code is below.

Please download the dataset from below link

https://github.com/udacity/nd027-Data-Engineering-Data-Lakes-AWS-Exercises/blob/main/lesson-2-spark-essentials/exercises/data/sparkify_log_small.json

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
from pyspark.sql.functions import asc
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as Fsum
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Wrangling Data Quiz") \
    .getOrCreate()
path = "/Users/mak/Downloads/sparkify_log_small.json"
user_log = spark.read.json(path)
user_log.createOrReplaceTempView("user_log")

user_window = Window \
    .partitionBy('userID') \
    .orderBy(desc('ts')) \
    .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

ishome = udf(lambda ishome : int(ishome == 'Home'), IntegerType())

# Filter only NextSong and Home pages, add 1 for each time they visit Home
# Adding a column called period which is a specific interval between Home visits
cusum = user_log.filter((user_log.page == 'NextSong') | (user_log.page == 'Home')) \
    .select('userID', 'page', 'ts') \
    .withColumn('homevisit', ishome(col('page'))) \
    .withColumn('period', Fsum('homevisit') \
    .over(user_window)) 
    
# See how many songs were listened to on average during each period
cusum.filter((cusum.page == 'NextSong')) \
    .groupBy('userID', 'period') \
    .agg({'period':'count'}) \
    .agg({'count(period)':'avg'}) \
    .show()
```

My output is
avg(count(period)):  6.898347107438017

When I change to Pyspark sql syntax

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, sum as Fsum, avg
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Create or get the Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Wrangling Data Quiz").getOrCreate()

# Path to your JSON file
path = "/Users/makbulhussain/Downloads/sparkify_log_small.json"

# Read JSON data and create a DataFrame
user_log = spark.read.json(path)
user_log.createOrReplaceTempView("user_log")

# Create a UDF to determine if the page is Home
def ishome_udf(page):
    return int(page == 'Home')

# Register the UDF
spark.udf.register("ishome_udf", ishome_udf)

# Filter only NextSong and Home pages, add 1 for each time they visit Home
# Adding a column called period which is a specific interval between Home visits
cusum = spark.sql("""
    SELECT userID, page, ts,
           SUM(ishome_udf(page)) OVER (PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY ts DESC) AS period
    FROM user_log
    WHERE page = 'NextSong' OR page = 'Home'
""")

# Calculate the average songs listened during each period
result = cusum.filter(cusum.page == 'NextSong').groupBy("userID", "period").agg(
    Fsum("period").alias("songs_per_period")
)

# Calculate the average of songs listened during each period
overall_avg_result = result.groupBy().agg(
    avg("songs_per_period").alias("avg_songs_per_period")
)

# Show the result
# result.show()
overall_avg_result.show()
```

I got output is avg_songs_per_period: 8.314049586776859

Can we tell while converting dataframe to sql what happend wrong